# Debug in Aptana Studio

Tags: debugging, aptana

I'm trying to debug a Yii application in Aptana Studio. It works OK to debug the first page, but when I try to visit another page it says "Error opening file: No such file or directory". I think it has something to do with htaccess file (url rewriting). How can I enable htaccess file when debugging?

This is my htaccess file:

```
# Enabling symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
    # Defending against clickjacking
    Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</ifmodule>

<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ho96.com

    #www. added automatically to my domain ONLY IF a subdomain is not already there. Subdomains bypass this redirect.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

    # If a directory or a file exists, use it directly, otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # Redirecting IP to domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^160\.153\.85\.7
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.ho96.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    # Compressing text, html, javascript, css, xml:
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>

<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    # File caching (5 minutes = A300; 1 week = A604800; 1 month = A2419200; 1 year = A29030400)
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A604800 
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/html A300
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    ExpiresActive Off
    </FilesMatch> 
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: what is the path of your website? is it in a subdirectory? if so, do you or do you not have a `RewriteBase` set?

Comment: The path of my website is http://localhost/ho96.com . I've added RewriteBase but it's not working :(

Comment: Did you do `RewriteBase /ho96.com` ? or what did you try?

Comment: Exactly. And I get this error: Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/ho96.com/en/contact

Error opening file: No such file or directory

Comment: so.... edit your post (do not post a comment) and when you edit your post everything that is in your .htaccess file

Comment: ok, I've just edited the post.